# Android Custom Spinner with Image selection

Tags: java, android, user-interface, spinner

I am working on a custom spinner, I already understand how to use an ArrayAdapter in order to customise the layout of the custom popup.

The issue I am having however is that I do not want to show the default spinner on my UI instead I want to show an image, then this image will changed based on the item that has been selected, the image would look something like below:

[image]

Further to this, is there a way that I can use wrap_content, but to wrap it based on this image size rather than the default spinner size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want one layout for the value shown in the Spinner proper (layoutA), and a different one (layoutB) for the spinner option views in the popup window?

If that's the case, then it's very simple: in the adapter's constructor, pass layoutA. And then call `setDropDownViewResource()` with layoutB.

Alternatively, if you have a custom adapter class, you can achieve the same result by overriding `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` respectively.

Setting the spinner's height to `WRAP_CONTENT` should work in this scenario (although I haven't tested that particular bit).

Comment: I have a custom adapter class and am already using getDropDownView() which contains an ImageView. I then use this line imgItemSel.setImageResource(R.drawable.battle_magic); however this does not see to be doig anything. Also the "wrap_content" IS NOT working, any ideas?

Comment: @LandLPartners I've tested it and it works. Perhaps I misunderstood the question? See this gist: https://gist.github.com/matiash/22313740c47fe1d63604

Comment: The problem is all my data is going to be dynamic nothing is static and I cannot seem to get the image to change upon selection from the dropdown. I have added my code here http://pastebin.com/uqBELCPp

Comment: You don't need to set a new adapter from `onItemSelected()`, just let the Adapter draw the current view. Although my example was with static data, it could be easily be dynamic, you just need to call notifyDataSetChanged() after updating it.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite follow, also forgot to mention that my dynamic data is constantly changing and in theory could change everytime the popup is selected. Could you please provide some sample code, as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When the data changes, call `clear()` on the Adapter, then `add()` or `addAll()`, then `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The bound view (Spinner in this case) will redraw itself.

Comment: Sorry i really dont follow, my logic works fine in terms of filling the spinnner. The issue I have is getting the image to change once the item has been selected from the dropdown. So the not the image on te dropdown the one on the ui.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54736/discussion-between-matiash-and-landl-partners).

Answer (score 0):

Well its very easy to implement either you use `switch case` or `if else` both will work fine. I have implement this one using `if else` condition by attaching image source to each argument that I have declared.

Here is example of code.

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        //spinner.
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(arg2==0)
            {

                imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
            }
            else if(arg2==1)
            {
                imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.microsoft);
            }
            else
            {
                imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.google);
            }
```

Source - http://kamleshnishad.com/android-studio-spinner-example-onclick-change-image/